# How to delete a node after "x" days - Node expiration date?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking to delete a node after a certain time, let's say that I want to place the node an expiration date of 5 days and in those 5 days delete the node. How can I do it?

My data structure is like this:

```
 Posts:
      PushedKey:value
```

How can I delete this `pushedKey` after certain time?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using Cloud Functions for Firebase. You can use an external service for cron jobs, using it to trigger an HTTP function at a certain time interval. Granted, this would be the same interval for all of the nodes instead of a timer counting down five days for each individual node. But, for example, you could trigger the function once a day and remove all nodes that were written to the database 5 days ago.

[Here's a similar example applied to removing unused accounts](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron)

[Here's the documentation on Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

Comment: Thanks! i will see this :D